# What is the better way to add first time signed-up user relationship in firebase while login?

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a teaching app where I have to create a relationship for teacher-student.
Teachers are the first who gets to log in to the app. Now I need to add a student in the teacher's collection while student signup first or any way.
I was planning to send a unique id for signup to the student, for example,
`http://localhost:3000/signup?teacherId=1982828989` and while the student signup successfully, it gets added up in the 1982828989 teacher's student collection.
Is there a better approach to do this? or any other approaches what firebase gives out of the box?

Comment: Doesn't that give away some hints about the structure of your database (security wise)? Isn' it better to give the student a hashed version of the id? or a code that is decoupled from your database?

Comment: I am a bit confused here with the approach, would be so kind as to add a bit explanation and example maybe with different approaches?

Comment: I would add a list of the teachers right in the login screen for the students and let them choose the teacher they are meant to associate with. The teacher document would have a database ID however they would only get to see their Name/Class.

Comment: That an idea I had in mind too, but issue with that is I have to download the whole teacher's collection, thats too much exposing. Plus the name can be the same, would create an issue.

Comment: Maybe you can use json web tokens? Something like this https://medium.com/@furqanaziz/implement-email-verification-using-jwt-282e9344218d But not to verify a email address but use the code/link to register a student.

Comment: Thinking on same names, made me think on adding the "Class" too. And for the names I would try to shorten some last names, so that the student can differenciate. No need to download the whole teachers collections if you can store the relevant data of the teacher's list in a single document either as a map or an array, the only issue there could be the amount of reads to that document.

Comment: @Karlan, I hear what you saying, well the teacher id I was talking about is the same as jwt which is created by firebase.

Comment: @Racu, Yes I could pull up the only relevant documents I need, but still it's gonna be a long list. seems confusing for people to find the eright people. If I have 5000 teachers or more this will be confusing?

Comment: @SubhenduKundu, you are rigth, with 5000 my approach is not cost effective.

Comment: any other ideas? :(

Comment: [How to come up with students and teacher relation in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473242/how-to-come-up-with-students-and-teacher-relation-in-firebase) what about something like this one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though the question is more of when the students log in, link them to the teacher. Like a referral, and it gets added to the teacher.

Answer (score 0):

I like your solution to identify the teacher by link if he is already known before login.

I would suggest creating groups for each teacher and assign the user to the group. 
So you could send group ID instead. It will be also easier to change the teacher name for the group in case of change in the future.
It is recommended solution for scaling the database. It could look like that:

```
// An index to track Studen1 teachers
{
  "student": {
    "student-id-..": {
      "name": "Student Name",
      // Index of student teachers 
      "teachers": {
         // it can be also primary teachers
         "teacher-1-group-id-...": true,
         "teacher-2-group-id-...": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "teachers": {
    "teacher-1-group-id-...": {
      "name": "Teacher Name",
      "members": {
        "student-id-1...": true,
        "student-id-2...": true,
        "student-id-3...": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

If you like this solution, [please read more about it in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#fanout)